# Convert JSON object to a sequelize data model object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How do I convert a JSON object to sequelize model object ? I am using findOne method which returns me a sequelize model object. Then I convert this into a normal JSON object so that I can add some custom attributes in the JSON object. Once I have done this, is it possible to convert the normal JSON object back to a sequelize object ?

Comment: Can you give an example object and show your code?

Comment: Show that `findOne` query...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a JSON object. JSON is a text representation of an object, not the object itself. Typically if you want to alter something from the dbase, you use a sequelize method like findOne, you get an object, you change the properties on the object and then use object.save() to save it back to update the database with the new values.